# NSUserScriptTask: cancelling tasks?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstask, appstore-sandbox

Is there any way to cancel a running NSUserScriptTask? The only way that comes to mind is to launch a separate process (a command line tool) via NSTask, whose only purpose is to run the NSUserScriptTask, and then terminate the command line tool via NSTask when necessary. However, that seems a bit far-fetched and not very optimized... Any ideas?

Comment: I think you've already found the best answer to that.  The executor isn't intended to be cancelled.

Comment: Yeah, well, but if this is a replacement of sorts of the NSTask/NSAppleScript/AMWorkflow classes it should be able to be cancelled, right?

Comment: One would think, but there isn't any provision for it in the API at least.